# sudo yum install or reinstall

Tags: bash, yum, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I am deploying my nodejs app via EB onto a Linux EC2 and in the .ebextensions I need to install a font package and I must use yum:

```
container_commands:
  01_getfont: 
    command: sudo yum -y install http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

Unfortunately, while that works for the 1st time, it does not work for the 2nd time if I re-deploy again it will complain the package is there already.

So what I do is to use this:

```
command: sudo yum -y reinstall http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

Unfortunately, while that works for the 2nd times and so on, it does not work for the 1st time if the package is not there, giving the error:

```
Error: Problem in reinstall: no package matched to remove.
```

This is driving me nuts.

Is there a way around this? Not really good at Linux bash script, can I like if 1st time use this command else that command?

I can create a bash script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    sudo yum -y install http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

and so on...

Comment: Can you include the `remove` command before the `install` command?

Comment: Will remove fail if the package is not already there in the 1st place? @l'L'l I was actually thinking if we can suppress the failure and move onto the next step...

Comment: Yes, exactly... unfortunately I'm not familiar with `EB`, or what directives you can feed to it, although if you can include any type of clause (eg. `if`... or just move onto the next command if failure) then that's what I was thinking too. Can you run a `bash` script from the command? That's probably the best route, then you could just include everything there.

Comment: Yes I can run a bash script, will you be able to provide those as an answer @l'L'l I can create a bash script in ebextensions to be executed. See my updated question.

Comment: That’s good; Sure, I’ll put an answer together which will include how to handle whether the package is installed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned running a `shell` script is possible then it should be fairly easy to handle:

**webcore_install.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function isinstalled {
  status=$?
  if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]; then
    # reinstall if already present
    sudo yum -y reinstall http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
  else
    # install if not present
    sudo yum -y install http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm
  fi
}

yum -C list installed "$@"
isinstalled
```

Then your command could look something like this:

```
sudo ./path/to/webcore_install.sh webcore-fonts-3.0-1
```

You might need to change the permissions on the `shell` script also:

```
chmod +x webcore_install.sh
```

Comment: Thanks @l'L'l I discover a one-liner: sudo yum -q list installed webcore-fonts.noarch &>/dev/null && sudo yum -y reinstall http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm || sudo yum -y install http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, same basic principle there; either method should work for whatever packages you might want to do this with — cheers!